# Why does it take so long to see a completed transaction in history?

Tags: transaction, wallet

I work with the Light Wallet 2.5.4

After the computer has done the proof of work it says: "Transfer completed"
First of all I think this is very confusing, because obviously it is not completed but pending inside the tangle. And than I still have to wait a long time until I can even see this transaction inside the wallet history (with status "pending").

So now my question: "Why does it take so long until the completed transaction is shown inside the history?"

Comment: What do you mean by „completed“? Confirmed?